# Generate a certificate with Openssl and import the same certificate using keytool

Tags: ssl, tomcat, openssl, keytool, liferay

I have a question about the SSL during the use of CAS in LIferay.

I have generate the certificate using Openssl (I flollowed this [tutorial](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html)) on my CAS Server and now I would to import the certificate using keytool on the Liferay machine.
To import the certificate with keytool I use this command:

```
keytool -import -alias tomcatLiferay -file /myopensslcertificate.crt
```

But when I import the .crt certificate file and I check the CAS connection I get the message: `SSL Error`.
IF I try to generate the certificate using keytool (keytool -genkey...) on the CAS server end I import this certificate using keytool -import .... I can connect to the CAS server and I not see any errors...
I think that I use a wrong way to generate the certificate with openssl or a wrong way to import the certificate (generated with openssl) with keytool.

Answer (score 1):

the java keytool does not fully support PEM encoded (ascii) certificate files.
You could convert it to a DER encoded (binary) vertificate by issuing:

```
openssl x509 -in <der certificate file> -inform PEM 
-out <pem certificate file> -outform  DER
```

After converting the certificate to a supported format the keytool import should work.

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias <your alias> 
-file <der certificate file> -keystore <keystore-file>
```

[This blog post describes it in detail](http://www.devops-insight.com/2014/09/convert-certificates-pem-der.html)